# Trying get items from an arraylist to show in a grid

Tags: java, arraylist, javafx-8

Im trying to show my arraylist in a grid, but for some reason I cant get the arraylist to show. I have my main class underneath and also the class OrderMenu that contains my arraylist. I prefer to get the arraylist showing in grid because im trying to make a pizza ordering system, and the grid it easier for me to work with. Preferable it would be a grid with 12 rows a row for each item in the arraylist and two columns one for the name and one for the price.

Hoping that you guys can help.

```
public class PizzaOrderingSystem extends Application {  

private OrderMenu menu;
public ArrayList<MenuItem> menuItems;
private GridPane grid;
private BorderPane border;

//Creating Stage and layout for Stage
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {

    stage.setTitle("Pizza Ordering System");
    stage.setWidth(600);
    stage.setHeight(600);

    this.menu.menuItems.size();

    int numRows = 2;
    int numColumns = 12;

    for (int i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) {
    ColumnConstraints cc = new ColumnConstraints(40);
    cc.setPercentWidth(80);
    cc.setHalignment(HPos.CENTER);
    grid.getColumnConstraints().add(cc);

    for (int row = 0; row < numRows; row++) {
    RowConstraints rc = new RowConstraints(40);
    rc.setPercentHeight(80);
    rc.setValignment(VPos.CENTER);
    grid.getRowConstraints().add(rc);            }

    }   

    border.setCenter(grid);

    stage.setTitle("Pizza Ordering System");
    stage.setWidth(600);
    stage.setHeight(600);

    //Attacing borderPane to scene
    stage.setScene(new Scene(border));
    stage.getScene();
    stage.show();
    }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}  
}      

public class OrderMenu {


public ArrayList<MenuItem> menuItems;


public OrderMenu(){

            menuItems.add(new Pizza("Margherita", 50));
            menuItems.add(new Pizza("Hawaii", 55));
            menuItems.add(new Pizza("Marinara", 70));
            menuItems.add(new Pizza("Meat Lovers", 70));
            menuItems.add(new Pizza("Calzone", 60));

            menuItems.add(new Burger("Burger", 60));
            menuItems.add(new Burger("Cheeseburger", 65));
            menuItems.add(new Burger("Baconburger", 60));

            menuItems.add(new Soda("Coca cola", 25));
            menuItems.add(new Soda("Coca cola light", 25));             
            menuItems.add(new Soda("Fanta", 25));
            menuItems.add(new Soda("Faxe kondi", 25));
```

}

}

Comment: You have a call to the method "launch" in your main method but I can't see that method anywhere. This code is dependent on other classes not present in your question. It's hard to help you if you don't say what you mean by "I can't get it to work". Are you getting an error message? If so posting it would help people help you.

Comment: Sorry, ill just rephrase it a bit after I reply to your. I cant get my arraylist to show in a grid. It should be 12 rows with each item from the arraylist.

Comment: In your question you call a method called launch from the main method in your PizzaOrderingSystem class, presumably the launch method is part of the class called "Application" which the PizzaOrderingSystem class extends. It's impossible to say where the problem lies in your code because it cannot be established from what you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I can't see where you attempt to make use of the menuItems you create in your OrderMenu class. I don't think you mean them to be javafx menuItems. Also you don't seem to create instances of your private fields, so I assume they are all just null when you try and use them.

Here's a simplification of what you have that displays a list of pizzas and price on a grid. I've not added anything to size the app so it will look a bit scrunched up.

The main app

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PizzaOrderingSystem extends Application {  

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();

        int row = 0;
        for (OrderItem item : OrderMenu.getItems()) {
            grid.add(new Label(item.getName()), 0, row);
            grid.add(new Label(String.valueOf(item.getPrice())), 1, row);
            row++;
        }

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.setCenter(grid);

        stage.setTitle("Pizza Ordering System");

        stage.setScene(new Scene(borderPane));

        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }  
}
```

Interface for an OrderItem

```
public interface OrderItem {

    public String getName();
    public int getPrice();
}
```

a Pizza class that implements the OrderItem

```
public class Pizza implements OrderItem {

    private String name;
    private int price;

    public Pizza(String name, int price) {
        this.setName(name);
        this.setPrice(price);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

}
```

And an OrderMenu with a static method to get a list of order items.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class OrderMenu {

    public static List<OrderItem> getItems(){
        List<OrderItem> menuItems = new ArrayList<>();

        menuItems.add(new Pizza("Margherita", 50));
        menuItems.add(new Pizza("Hawaii", 55));
        menuItems.add(new Pizza("Marinara", 70));
        menuItems.add(new Pizza("Meat Lovers", 70));
        menuItems.add(new Pizza("Calzone", 60));

        return menuItems;
    }

}
```